# How do I change the camera's x and y based of a variable

Tags: javascript, p5.js

In https://editor.p5js.org/, if your canvas is too big, you have to scroll the canvas, is there a way to change it so when your player goes out of the canvas, the camera changes, so your player is always in the camera.
This is what I have so far. Also, is there a way to change the zoom based on the player size?

```
var playerX;
var playerY;
var playerSize = 10;
var playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 20;
var Newcelltimer = 0;
var cell = []
var cellEaten = 0;
var eaten = false;
var pull = 0;
var spawnTime = 100;
var spawnTimeUpgrader = 0;
function setup() {

  frameRate(50)
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  playerX = random(30, width - 30);
  playerY = random(30, height - 30);


}

function draw() {
  playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10


  Newcelltimer++;

  background(220);

  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && playerY - playerSize / 2 >= 0) {
    playerY -= playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && playerX + playerSize / 2 <= width) {
    playerX += playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW) && playerY + playerSize / 2 <= height) {
    playerY += playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && playerX - playerSize / 2 >= 0) {
    playerX -= playerSpeed;
  }

  if (Newcelltimer % spawnTime == 0) {
    cell.push(ceil(random(10, width - 10)),
      ceil(random(10, height - 10)))

  }

  for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {

    fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
    circle(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], 7)
  }



  fill(255, 255, 0)
  circle(playerX,playerY,playerSize)
  fill(0)
  ellipse(playerX - playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
  ellipse(playerX + playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
  arc(playerX, playerY + playerSize / 5, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
  fill(255, 255, 0)
  noStroke()
  arc(playerX, (playerY + playerSize / 5) - 1, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
  stroke(0)



  
  
  for(var i=0;i<cell.length/2;i++)
    {
  let d = int(dist(cell[i*2],cell[i*2+1],playerX,playerY))
  if(d<=playerSize/2+pull)
      {
       playerSize+=7;
       cell.splice(i*2,2)
      }
    }


  if (playerSize >= width | playerSize >= height) {
    if (width > height) {
      playerSize = height;
    } else {
      playerSize = width;
    }




  }
  // if (Newcelltimer % 500 === 0) {
  //   cell.splice(0, 2)
  // }

  if(pull>=50)
    {
      pull = 50;
    }


  fill(0)
  text("Your Size is: " + playerSize, 30, 30)
  text("Your pull is: "+pull,30,60)
  text("Upgrade your pull for "+pull*15+" size",430,45)
  text("Double Spawn Rate for " + 50*pow(2,spawnTimeUpgrader)+" size",430,100);
  fill(0,0,0,0)
  rect(410,75,187,40)
  rect(410,20,187,40)

   
}
//  function mouseClicked()
// {

//   if(mouseX>410&&mouseX<600&&mouseY>20&&mouseY<60&&playerSize-10>pull*15)
//     {
//       playerSize-=pull*15
//       pull+=10;
//     }
  

//  if(mouseX>410&&mouseX<600&&mouseY>75&&mouseY<115&&playerSize-10>50*pow(2,spawnTimeUpgrader))
//     {
//       playerSize-=50*pow(2,spawnTimeUpgrader);
//       spawnTime/=2;
//       spawnTimerUpgrader++;
//     }
// }
```

EDIT: I was able to make the camera change, here's the new one:

```
var playerX;
var playerY;
var playerSize = 10;
var playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 20;
var Newcelltimer = 0;
var cell = []
var cellEaten = 0;
var eaten = false;
var zoom = 1;
var newZoom = 64/playerSize
function setup() {

  frameRate(50)
  createCanvas(600, 450);
  playerX = random(30-width, width - 30);
  playerY = random(30-height, height - 30);


}

function draw() {
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  var newzoom = 64 / playerSize;
  zoom = lerp(zoom, newzoom, 0.00000001);
  scale(zoom);
  translate(-playerX, -playerY);
  console.log(lerp(zoom,newzoom,0.1))
  
  playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10


  Newcelltimer++;

  background(220);

  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)&&playerY>0-width) {
    playerY -= playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)&&playerX<2*width) {
    playerX += playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)&&playerY<2*width) {
    playerY += playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)&&playerX>0-width) {
    playerX -= playerSpeed;
  }

  if (Newcelltimer % 30 == 0) {
    cell.push(ceil(random(0-width,2*width)),
      ceil(random(0-height,2*height)))

  }

  for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {

    fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
    circle(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], 7)
  }



  fill(255, 255, 0)
  circle(playerX,playerY,playerSize)
  fill(0)
  ellipse(playerX - playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
  ellipse(playerX + playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
  arc(playerX, playerY + playerSize / 5, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
  fill(255, 255, 0)
  noStroke()
  arc(playerX, (playerY + playerSize / 5) - 1, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
  stroke(0)



  
  
  for(var i=0;i<cell.length/2;i++)
    {
  let d = int(dist(cell[i*2],cell[i*2+1],playerX,playerY))
  if(d<=playerSize/2)
      {
       playerSize+=7;
       cell.splice(i*2,2)
      }
    }


  if (playerSize >= 3*width | playerSize >= 3*height) {
    if (width > height) {
      playerSize = height;
    } else {
      playerSize = width;
    }




  }
  // if (Newcelltimer % 500 === 0) {
  //   cell.splice(0, 2)
  // }

  // if(pull>=50)
  //   {
  //     pull = 50;
  //   }


  fill(0)
  text("Your Size is: " + playerSize, playerX-270, playerY-200)
  // text("Your pull is: "+pull,30,60)
  // text("Upgrade your pull for "+pull*15+" size",430,45)
  // text("Double Spawn Rate for " + 50*pow(2,spawnTimeUpgrader)+" size",430,100);
  // fill(0,0,0,0)
  // rect(410,75,187,40)
  // rect(410,20,187,40)

   
}
//  function mouseClicked()
// {

//   if(mouseX>410&&mouseX<600&&mouseY>20&&mouseY<60&&playerSize-10>pull*15)
//     {
//       playerSize-=pull*15
//       pull+=10;
//     }
  

//  if(mouseX>410&&mouseX<600&&mouseY>75&&mouseY<115&&playerSize-10>50*pow(2,spawnTimeUpgrader))
//     {
//       playerSize-=50*pow(2,spawnTimeUpgrader);
//       spawnTime/=2;
//       spawnTimerUpgrader++;
//     }
// }
```

The problem I wasn't able to solve was the scaling with the size.

Comment: Note that Java is not JavaScript and your question seems to be purely about JavaScript. That being said, you could try to center everything around your player, i.e. move everything into the frame of reference of your player (e.g. if the player is at (300/100) an object at (4/3) would be moved to (-296/-97) in relation to the player). When rendering you might need another translation to take the player's position in relation to the canvas into account. Terms to research: world space, view space, projection space (often applied to 3D but 2D is just a simpler case)

Answer (score 1):

I can see by the code you have that you were very close.

The key components to scaling in p5.js are the [scale](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/scale) and the [translate](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/translate) function, both of which you were using just not quite what you needed!

More specifically, this is the code you're looking for:

```js
    translate(width/2, height/2);   // centres us to the middle of the screen
    scale(10/playerSize)            // scales the world according to player size
    translate(-playerX, -playerY);  // makes the player the centre of the world
```

So now when you play, when you eat some food, the player's view of the world increases.

```js
var playerX;
var playerY;
var playerSize = 10;
var playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 20;
var Newcelltimer = 0;
var cell = []
var cellEaten = 0;
var eaten = false;
var zoom = 1;

function setup() {
    frameRate(50)
    createCanvas(600, 450);
    playerX = width/2
    playerY = height/2;
}

function draw() {
  
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    scale(10/playerSize)
    translate(-playerX, -playerY);
  
    playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10


    Newcelltimer++;

    background(220);

    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && playerY > 0 - width) {
        playerY -= playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && playerX < 2 * width) {
        playerX += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW) && playerY < 2 * width) {
        playerY += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && playerX > 0 - width) {
        playerX -= playerSpeed;
    }

    if (Newcelltimer % 30 == 0) {
        cell.push(ceil(random(0 - width, 2 * width)),
            ceil(random(0 - height, 2 * height)))

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {

        fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
        circle(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], 7)
    }



    fill(255, 255, 0)
    circle(playerX, playerY, playerSize)
    fill(0)
    ellipse(playerX - playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
    ellipse(playerX + playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
    arc(playerX, playerY + playerSize / 5, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
    fill(255, 255, 0)
    noStroke()
    arc(playerX, (playerY + playerSize / 5) - 1, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
    stroke(0)




    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {
        let d = int(dist(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], playerX, playerY))
        if (d <= playerSize / 2) {
            playerSize += 7;
            cell.splice(i * 2, 2)
        }
    }


    if (playerSize >= 3 * width | playerSize >= 3 * height) {
        if (width > height) {
            playerSize = height;
        } else {
            playerSize = width;
        }
    }

}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the text which tells your size, always at the corner of the screen? With this, because the text is based off the player position, the larger the zoom get's, the closer the text get's to the opposite corner.

Comment: Yes there's a way, but it's not the question you initially asked. I'd suggest - if I've answered your initial question - accepting the answer and creating a new question if you're still stuck :)